# Parsing and validating Aadhar paperless offline eKYC?

Tags: xml, aadhaar

I generated my offline eKYC XML using https://resident.uidai.gov.in/offline-kyc.

The XML tag, including the signature is like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><OfflinePaperlessKyc referenceId="someID"><UidData><Poi dob="08-09-1984" e="encrypted email" gender="M" m="encrypted mobile" name="Name"/><Poa careof="" country="India" dist="Pune" house="Address" landmark="" loc="Address2 " pc="411045" po="N.i.a." state="Maharashtra" street="" subdist="Pune City" vtc="Pune City"/><Pht>encoded</Pht></UidData><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>LbEZZGdjoI0359QTtFJxO+53xdkWgzRhGdSb+gspDKk=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>encoded signature</SignatureValue></Signature></OfflinePaperlessKyc>
```

Now, we need to validate the info in this XML, like mobile/email etc., against info in our system, which is being used by the user,

I looked for Uidai's site looking for developer guides and found through https://uidai.gov.in/2-uncategorised/11320-aadhaar-paperless-offline-e-kyc-3.html

This has a section -
Technical Facets of Aadhaar Paperless Offline e-KYC

However, the components of the XML are not exactly matching with what I have in my doc.

I don't have signature under `s=`. I have as specified above.

Also, dob is present under `dob` tag in my xml. In this guide, it is given `d=` though.

Also, the signature in my case is 348 characters, whereas the guide mentions 344 characters.

Can someone guide with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your generated KYC XML response is correct. Go with this response. Actually they improve system day by day.
For more updated information check below link

https://uidai.gov.in/ecosystem/authentication-devices-documents/about-aadhaar-paperless-offline-e-kyc.html

Q . dob is present under dob tag in my xml. In this guide, it is given d= though.

> dob is correct tag as per above link.

Q . signature in my case is 348 characters, whereas the guide mentions 344 characters.

> As per UIDAI, Signature: – This will a 344 character long digital signature of the data present in the downloaded XML. This can be validated using the public key of UIDAI which will be present in standard signed xml.

I am not sure about Signature value but try with this Signature or download new xml. Now your xml is version 1.0. After new download it may be upgrade as per mention above link.